# Using ignore on column in Room android

Tags: android, android-room

My DB table is as

```
@Entity
internal data class ConversationEntity(
@PrimaryKey val conversationId: String,
val status: String,
val createdAt: String,
val modifiedAt: String,
val lastMessage: String? = null,
val feedbackType: ChatFeedbackType? = null
)
```

I want to use `@Ignore` on `lastMessage` but it gives me below error.

```
@Entity
internal data class ConversationEntity(
@PrimaryKey val conversationId: String,
val status: String,
val createdAt: String,
val modifiedAt: String,
@Ignore
val lastMessage: String? = null,
val feedbackType: ChatFeedbackType? = null)
```

The error I get

```
Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

What is wrong here?

My dao is

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  abstract suspend fun saveConversations(entities: List<ConversationEntity>)
```

My current DB version is 6. Would I also need to write migration query for adding ignore?

Comment: I think the `internal` modifier for the entity data class is causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **@Ignore** the @Ignore is not included in the table thus Room expects a constructor that it can use for inserting/extracting rows rather than the full default constructor.

As such you need to add a suitable constructor that doesn't include the lastMessage

After resolving the constructor issue you will then, I believe, encounter an issue as Conversation isn't public. You can resolve this by removing the **internal** keyword.

e.g.

```
@Entity
data class ConversationEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val conversationId: String,
    val status: String,
    val createdAt: String,
    val modifiedAt: String,
    @Ignore
    val lastMessage: String? = null,
    val feedbackType: ChatFeedbackType? = null) {
    constructor(
        conversationId: String,
        status: String,
        createdAt: String,
        modifiedAt: String,
        feedbackType: ChatFeedbackType):
            this(conversationId,status,createdAt,modifiedAt,null,feedbackType)
}
```

- this assumes that you have a TypeConverter for ChatFeedbackType

As an example of the above (using String for feedbackType for convenience)

and a dao:-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(entities: List<ConversationEntity>)
```

and using:-

```
    val conversations = listOf<ConversationEntity>(
        ConversationEntity("Conv1","blah","2021-06-25 09:00:00","2021-06-25 10:00:00","NONE"),
        ConversationEntity("Conv2","blah","2021-06-25 09:00:00","2021-06-25 10:00:00","NONE"),
        ConversationEntity("Conv1","blah","2021-06-26 09:00:00","2021-06-26 10:00:00","NONE")
    )
    dao.insert(conversations)
```

Then the ConversationEntity table after running is:-

[image]

- i.e. the two rows have been added and the first replaced.

**HOWEVER**

Ignoring a field/variable makes it so that Room will never populate that value so effectively it makes the ignored fields pretty useless being coded in an entity.

As an example if your wanted to populate `lastMessage` by calculating it based upon a query say for example purposes:-

```
@Query("SELECT *, 'calculated data' AS lastMessage FROM conversationentity")
fun getConversations(): List<ConversationEntity>
```

- which you may think would populate the ignored lastMessage field/variable with the value `calculated data` (literal rather than an expression (which could be a sub-query))

  - a literal has been used for convenience/brevity
- However Room will issue a warning e.g. `warning: The query returns some columns [lastMessage] which are not used by ....` and as the constructor used/selected by room is incomplete constructor added when extracting the ConversationEntity the calculated value is not paced into the `lastMessage` field/variable (even though it is available).

I would suggest, if the intention is to populate the ignored values from the database that you consider the entity as a partial class and have a POJO as the complete class that Embeds the Entity. e.g.

Have **ConversationEntity** as :-

```
@Entity
data class ConversationEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val conversationId: String,
    val status: String,
    val createdAt: String,
    val modifiedAt: String,
    val feedbackType: String? = null) {
}
```

- String instead of **ChatFeedbackType** for the demo/example

and then have a POJO e.g.

```
data class ConversationEntityPojo (
    @Embedded
    var conversationEntity: ConversationEntity,
    var lastMessage: String?
)
```

- so as you see no need for the constructor nor for the @Ignore, but instead the more complete POJO.

Following on from the previous code used for testing but now with the modified Entity and POJO then using the following @Query's for demonstration :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM conversationentity")
fun getConversationsEntityOnly(): List<ConversationEntity>
@Query("SELECT *, 'calculated data' AS lastMessage FROM conversationentity")
fun getConversationsEntityOnlyWithLastMessage(): List<ConversationEntity>
@Query("SELECT * FROM conversationentity")
fun getConversationsPOJO(): List<ConversationEntityPojo>
@Query("SELECT *,'calculated data' AS lastMessage FROM conversationentity")
fun getConversationPOJOWithLastMessage(): List<ConversationEntityPojo>
```

and then using :-

```
    .... code from  previous example
    dao.insert(conversations)

    for(c: ConversationEntity in dao.getConversationsEntityOnly()) {
        Log.d("CONVINFO",
            "Conversation is ${c.conversationId} " +
                    "status is ${c.status} " +
                    "created ${c.createdAt} " +
                    "modified ${c.modifiedAt} "
                     // CANT DO THIS AS ENTITY doesn't have lastMessage field "lastmessage ${c.lastMessage}"
            )
    }
    for (c: ConversationEntity in dao.getConversationsEntityOnlyWithLastMessage()) {
        Log.d("CONVINFO",
            "Conversation is ${c.conversationId} " +
                    "status is ${c.status} " +
                    "created ${c.createdAt} " +
                    "modified ${c.modifiedAt} "
            // CANT DO THIS AS ENTITY doesn't have lastMessage field "lastmessage ${c.lastMessage}"
        )
    }
    for(c: ConversationEntityPojo in dao.getConversationsPOJO()) {
        Log.d("CONVINFO",
            "Conversation is ${c.conversationEntity.conversationId} " +
                    "status is ${c.conversationEntity.status} " +
                    "created ${c.conversationEntity.createdAt} " +
                    "modified ${c.conversationEntity.modifiedAt} " +
                    "lastmessage ${c.lastMessage}") /* Will not be populated as lastMessage is not available in extracted data*/
    }
    for(c: ConversationEntityPojo in dao.getConversationPOJOWithLastMessage()) {
        Log.d("CONVINFO",
            "Conversation is ${c.conversationEntity.conversationId} " +
                    "status is ${c.conversationEntity.status} " +
                    "created ${c.conversationEntity.createdAt} " +
                    "modified ${c.conversationEntity.modifiedAt} " +
                    "lastmessage ${c.lastMessage}") /* can be used */
    }
```

Then the result is :-

```
2021-06-27 12:26:38.919 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv2 status is blah created 2021-06-25 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-25 10:00:00 
2021-06-27 12:26:38.919 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv1 status is blah created 2021-06-26 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-26 10:00:00 


2021-06-27 12:26:38.920 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv2 status is blah created 2021-06-25 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-25 10:00:00 
2021-06-27 12:26:38.920 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv1 status is blah created 2021-06-26 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-26 10:00:00 


2021-06-27 12:26:38.924 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv2 status is blah created 2021-06-25 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-25 10:00:00 lastmessage null
2021-06-27 12:26:38.924 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv1 status is blah created 2021-06-26 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-26 10:00:00 lastmessage null


2021-06-27 12:26:38.926 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv2 status is blah created 2021-06-25 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-25 10:00:00 lastmessage calculated data
2021-06-27 12:26:38.927 D/CONVINFO: Conversation is Conv1 status is blah created 2021-06-26 09:00:00 modified 2021-06-26 10:00:00 lastmessage calculated data
```

Comment: "Ignoring a field/variable makes it so that Room will never populate that value `so effectively it makes the ignored fields pretty useless being coded in an entity`". Several hours spent to demonstrate this myself. I would have liked to have a more clear documentation available than the official one (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#ignore). Anyway, thanks @MikeT

Answer (score 0):

use this class for entity

```
class ConversationEntity (){

@PrimaryKey
val conversationId: String
val status: String
val createdAt: String
val modifiedAt: String
@Ignore
val lastMessage: String? = null
val feedbackType: ChatFeedbackType? = null

}
```